# how to read data frame having multiple json value in same columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

i loaded a json file into a dataframe using 
    pd.read_json.
One of the column named Info has the data in the form of
{'name': 'john', 'lname': 'buck', 'address': '101 N state'}

there are 3 other columns with normal value like id, date, post

Q - how to extract all the rows from a dataframe where lname = 'buck'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.io.json.json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)  to flatten the Info column to separate columns in your dataframe.

```html
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df_norm = json_normalize(df, 'Info', ['id', 'date', 'post'])
```

Then you can query the normalized dataframe as you wish:

```
df_norm.query("lname == 'buck'")
```